# Dynamic method name in an API call (AngularJS/$resource)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a component that uses a service to make API calls using $resource.  The component uses `get`, `update` (put) and `remove` (delete) that are all defined and working in the service.

I'd like to refactor the api call to one function that calls the appropriate method (passed in as a parameter).  For instance, rather than `MenusApi.get()...`, `MenusApi.update()...`, and `MenusApi.remove()...`, I'd like to call a function `callMenusApi(method)` that would take the passed `method` (`get`, `update` or `delete`) parameter as the api method.

```
callMenusApi('get');

function callMenusApi(method) {
     MenusApi.method()...
}
```

The issue I am having is Angular/JS doesn't recognise `method` in `MenusApi.method` as the parameter.  How do I interpolate the parameter `method` as the method in the api call?

Answer (score 1):

In your example you're trying to call object method called literally 'method'.. You have to use bracket syntax for dynamic method name. Try this:

```
function callMenusApi(method) {
     MenusApi[method]()...
}
```